# Embed youtube video without youtube link

Tags: jquery, ajax, video, mootools, youtube

as you know that when you Embed youtube video in your web page, it works fine , but if you click on any part of screen, youtube website will open in new window.

is there any way to Embed youtube video in our website, but disable that youtube website opening when click on screen to pause the video?

or you can play you tube video in other player..?

i am looking for way around it.

any way possibility in j query, ajax, java script or PHP, mootools etc.
Thanks

Comment: Technically? Possibly, but it would be a violation of section 6.1.F of the YouTube terms of service. Video uses a lot of bandwidth, the link and logo are the price you pay for using Google's.

Comment: actually i don't mind to have their logo, its fine but the thing i don't like is click function, one you click to pause the video you go to you tube site, can we only disable it?

Comment: I think you may be out of luck on this one... I've looked into this a couple times and never came up with anything.

Comment: Host your own man! That'd be epic. Just get Lighttpd set up to serve video and get some flowplayer or maybe even some http://jilion.com/sublime/video when it's released!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this:

it is from youtube API sample, so it should be official supported
important is `&version=3` or `&something=xx;version=3`

```
<object style="height: 390px; width: 640px">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/u1zgFlCw8Aw?version=3">
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/u1zgFlCw8Aw?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" height="390"></object>
```

Comment: Confused -- does this represent a violation of youtube terms of service? If someone like Facebook did this to embedded youtube videos, would youtube sue?

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't do that. If you need a video-host who keeps their branding off of your screen, I suggest http://blip.tv. You can transfer your videos there via a FTP (they make it available to all users), and even customize your own player with your own branding.

Comment: i try this  vote down check
 
http://blip.tv but its so slow, i prefer to use youtube , with their logo or water mark, can we just disable click.?

Comment: No, air. You can't disable their click.

Answer (score 2):

there are a few ways to do this like (depending on your programmer skills):

REQUIRE JS knowledge:
- use the JS api from google and disable the normal buttons and add customs buttons and events (there are a lot of examples in their documentation)

NO PROGRAMMER skills:

- use another player
- and the way i did: i put a DIV ontop of the player (except the part where the seek/controls are). This prevents the user to click on a  desired part of the embedded player but allows you to still use the controls (play/pause/seek/view in youtube)

USAGE for above solutions:
 - if you want to click on the player and trigger an action without starting to play the Youtube video
- disable: youtube click / open youtube in another window

HOPE THIS WILL HELP YOU

Answer (score 1):

The other way to embed YouTube videos on web pages is through platforms that have integrated YouTube's API into their software. Using these online platforms you can embed YouTube videos collectively in the form of a widget.

You can embed YouTube videos through different sources like Channels, Playlists, Shorts, Keywords and Locations using (https://app.taggbox.com/widget)

By this process, you can generate a unique embed code for yourself, which you can embed anywhere you want onto the website page without YouTube link. This single line code is comprises of HTML, CSS, Javascript attributes which makes it responsive and user friendly on websites.

Answer (score 0):

use Jw player and add this code to your page

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='swfobject.js'></script>
<div id='mediaspace'>This text will be replaced</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  var so = new SWFObject('http://astra.pcriot.com/videos/player.swf','ply','400','315','9','#000000');
  so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
  so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
  so.addParam('wmode','opaque');
  so.addVariable('file','http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQmt8uHgIGY');
  so.write('mediaspace');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the Youtube API with this script which will also allow you to specify specific timecode and display only a portion of the video.

```
<div videoID="" startTime="" endTime="" height="" width="" id="youtube"></div>

var n = "youtube";
var y = document.createElement('script');
y.type = "text/javascript";
y.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(y, s);
var player;
var p = document.getElementById(n);
var st = p.getAttribute("startTime");
var et = p.getAttribute("endTime");
var vi = p.getAttribute("videoID");
var ph = p.getAttribute("height");
var pw = p.getAttribute("width");

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player(n, {
        height: ph,width: pw,playerVars: {
            'rel': 0,
            'showinfo': 0,
            'hidecontrols': 1
        },

        events: {
            'onReady': lv
        }
    })
}

function lv(e) {
    e.target.cueVideoById({
        videoId: vi,startSeconds: st,endSeconds: et
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<?=$idtube?>?modestbranding=1&amp;;showinfo=0&amp;;autohide=1&amp;;rel=0&amp;;hd=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```