# How to use SWFObject correctly

Tags: javascript, events, youtube, youtube-api, swfobject

I am using SWFObject to embed YouTube videos into our website. There are many links to videos in one page and each link clears a wrapper div, then loads a new embed into it, with this code:

```
$('a.video-link').each(function () {
    $(this).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if ($('#video-wrap').has('object').length == 0) {
            var params = { allowScriptAccess: 'always', allowFullScreen: 'true' };
            var atts = { id: 'ytapiplayer' };
            swfobject.embedSWF($(this).attr('href'), 'ytapiplayer', '1000', '562', '8', null, null, params, atts);
            $('#video-wrap').show();
        } else {
            $('#video-wrap').find('object').remove();
            $(this).trigger('click');
        }
    });
});
```

These are the Youtube links I am using for each embed:

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/{Youtube ID}?hl=en_US&rel=0&hd=1&border=0&version=3&fs=1&autoplay=1&autohide=1&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytapiplayer
```

Then, here is the onYouTubePlayerReady() event handler:

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(id) {
    console.log('youtube player is ready.');
    var ytplayer = document.getElementById('ytapiplayer');
    ytplayer.addEventListener('onStateChange', 'onYouTubePlayerStateChange');
    ytplayer.addEventListener('onError', 'onYouTubePlayerError');
}
```

**All videos load fine, however the onYouTubePlayerReady is never hit!**

I have tried solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083128/youtube-api-not-firing-onyoutubeplayerready) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001558/embed-youtube-video-without-youtube-link) but nothing worked :(

Please help me solve this problem. **The ultimate goal is to get the Youtube API to work.**

Thanks.

EDIT: I tried to play with the code, make sure all names are correct, separate into different script tags and/or .js file, load it on the beginning, inside document.ready(), still, onYouTubePlayerReady is not firing. **What do you think?**

Comment: After SWFObject has embedded the player, inspect the DOM node and check that allowscriptaccess="always" is being set correctly.

Comment: It was being set correctly... I got it working, and will add an answer with the correct code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the working code:

Executing SWFObject on each video link:

```
$('a.video-link').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // SWFObjects loads a video object into div with ID ytapiplayer.
    // If the wrapper div already contains a video we need to remove it first:
    if ($('#video-wrap').has('object').length == 0) {
        var params = { allowScriptAccess: 'always', allowFullScreen: 'true' };
        var atts = { id: 'ytapiplayer' };
        swfobject.embedSWF($(this).attr('href'), 'ytapiplayer', '1000', '562', '8', null, null, params, atts);

        $('#video-wrap').show();
    } else {
        $('#video-wrap').find('object').remove();
        $(this).trigger('click');
    }
});
```

The YouTube link with API values:

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/' + data.YoutubeLink + '?hl=en_US&rel=0&hd=1&border=0&version=3&fs=1&autoplay=1&autohide=1&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytapiplayer
```

And the SWFObject event handlers **I put this code in a separate .js file, loaded before the code executing SWFObject. I don't know if it's necessary, but it's working anyway:**

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(id) {
    // We need the actual DOM element for this, if we want to use more advanced API.
    // This is because addEventListener activates the API.
    var ytplayer = $('#ytapiplayer').get(0);
    ytplayer.addEventListener('onStateChange', 'onYouTubePlayerStateChange'); // onYouTubePlayerStateChange(newState)
    ytplayer.addEventListener('onError', 'onYouTubePlayerError'); // onYouTubePlayerError(errorCode)
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's necessary. The onYouTubePlayerReady should be available before you make any requests to YouTube. In the future, you should test it by manually calling the function before or after your embedSWF call.

Comment: That's a great idea. Indeed, I was aware that SWFObject requires defining onYouTubePlayerReady before the API call, and indeed in a different website I didn't have any issues with this at all. However in this project, I guess separating the code into two files made it work.

Comment: You probably didn't have any problems because it's what's know as a 'race condition'. The timing of the HTTP request to load the YouTube player is racing the browser which is loading the JavaScript. It's an insidious type of bug.

Comment: I searched for some background about how race conditions happen in JS but all I could find was people asking help on how to solve them. Do you have a source with some information about JS race conditions?

Comment: It's not specific to JavaScript. It's a problem in all electronic systems (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). With JavaScript, you just need to be cognizant about the order of things being loaded, when HTTP requests are being executed in parallel, and when they're asynchronous. In this specific case, I would simply advise you to be ready to receive a third party before you make a request to the third party.

Comment: I feel like I'm nagging but still, could you please go into more depth on that last part - "be ready to receive a third party before you make a request to the third party"?

Comment: It's another way of saying what you already know: the function has to be "loaded before the code that executes SWFObject".